# How to read register value using ahk

Tags: autohotkey

I used readprocessmemory for get value of address. but it is not read register value.

How to read or write register value using autohotkey?

Answer (score 0):

You can use classMemory from [this repo](https://github.com/Kalamity/classMemory) for that.

here's a usage example:

```
#Include classMemory.ahk

vlc := new _ClassMemory("ahk_exe vlc.exe")
address = % "0x0425A584"      ; get the address from Cheat Engine and paste it here
msgbox, % vlc.read(address)   ; read volume
vlc.Write(address, 10)        ; write
msgbox, % vlc.read(address)   ; read again
```